# Default color from link won't change

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I know it's a basic question, but I can't change the color of a link, so can you please help me.
In this code, I have normally a small movie with an description/hyperlink to a page of my website 
*(first CSS and then HTML)*

```css
 /* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
 top:100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
 font-family:Century Gothic;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 font-family:Century Gothic;
 font-size:25px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
} 
#links:link  {
 
    color:inherit;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition:color 1s;
}
#links:hover {
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <!-- The video -->
 <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="vid/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

  <!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
 <div class="content">
  <h1>La Team en action!</h1>
  <p>Viens voir toute la team NoMaD en action! Disponible sur <span id="links"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCx9wXRznZvavCSXkbrJoDYw?view_as=subscriber">YouTube</a></span>, <span id="links"><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/teamn0mad">Twitch</a></span>, et  <span id="links"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/la_team_nomad">Insta</a></span>.</p>
  <!-- Use a button to pause/play the video with JavaScript -->
   <button id="myBtn" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Réseaux</button>
</div> 
</div>
```

Please help me ! I have to learn the basics… (I have already see in other tutos, but it doesn't work…).

Comment: Need to target the `a` in the style. So `#links a` and `#links a:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply this style to the `<a>` tag, not the `<span>`. But more importantly, you're using the same id of `links` twice, which is not legal. Change it to a class instead:

```
<p>Viens voir toute la team NoMaD en action! Disponible sur <span id="links"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCx9wXRznZvavCSXkbrJoDYw?view_as=subscriber">YouTube</a></span>, <span class="links"><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/teamn0mad">Twitch</a></span>, et  <span class="links"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/la_team_nomad">Insta</a></span>.</p>
```

Then change your CSS to select on this class instead of the id:

```
.links a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition:color 1s;
}

.links a:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
 top:100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
 font-family:Century Gothic;
}

/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */
#myBtn {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 font-family:Century Gothic;
 font-size:25px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
} 
#links:link  {
 
    color:inherit;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition:color 1s;
}
#links:hover {
 color:white;
}
a{color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <!-- The video -->
 <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="vid/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

  <!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
 <div class="content">
  <h1>La Team en action!</h1>
  <p>Viens voir toute la team NoMaD en action! Disponible sur <span id="links"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCx9wXRznZvavCSXkbrJoDYw?view_as=subscriber">YouTube</a></span>, <span id="links"><a href="https://www.twitch.tv/teamn0mad">Twitch</a></span>, et  <span id="links"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/la_team_nomad">Insta</a></span>.</p>
  <!-- Use a button to pause/play the video with JavaScript -->
   <button id="myBtn" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Réseaux</button>
</div> 
</div>
```